# Spring MVC + Spring Security + Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, annotations

I have a Spring 4 MVC web app which uses JPA repositories and Hibernate to map objects to a MySQL database.
I have to configure Spring Security via java class. Authentication from main page works correctly and redirect me to /admin or /user pages.
But I have a trouble: when i type in browser localhost:8080/admin - I go to the admin page, even if it is not to enter username and password.
Please show me to my mistake in config and/or in controller

my SecurityConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan("com.easygoapp.service")
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
@Autowired
@Qualifier("customUserDetailsService")
private UserDetailsService customUserDetailService;

//It's autowired ! Idea not correct views this!
@Autowired
private AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth;

@Autowired
AuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler;


@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(customUserDetailService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    // CSRF protection
    http.csrf()
            .disable()
                    // requests rules
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/assets/**", "/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().permitAll()
            .and();

    http.formLogin()
            // login form page
            .loginPage("/")
            .loginProcessingUrl("/j_spring_security_check")
                    // URL login not success
            .successHandler(successHandler)
            .failureUrl("/login?error")
            .usernameParameter("j_username")
            .passwordParameter("j_password")
                    // add permissions to login page to all
            .permitAll();

    http.logout()
            // add permissions to logout to all
            .permitAll()
                    // logout URL
            .logoutUrl("/logout")
                    // logout successful URL
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
                    // invalidation of current session
            .invalidateHttpSession(true);

    http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/admin/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
            .antMatchers("/user/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN') or hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
            .and().formLogin();
}

@Bean
@Override
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(customUserDetailService);
    return auth.build();
}


@Bean
public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}

@Bean
public AuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler() {
    return new CustomSuccessHandler();
}
```

My LoginController.java

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {

@Autowired
BCryptPasswordEncoder encoder;

@Autowired
UserService userService;


@RequestMapping(value = {"/", "/login"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView logged() {
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
    model.setViewName("index");
    return model;
}

@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
@RequestMapping(value = "/admin**", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView adminPage() {
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
    model.setViewName("admin");
    return model;
}

@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
@RequestMapping(value = "/user**", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView dbaPage() {

    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
    model.addObject("title", "Spring Security Hello World");
    model.addObject("message", "This is protected page - USER Page!");
    model.setViewName("message");

    return model;
}

//for 403 access denied page
@RequestMapping(value = "/403", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView accesssDenied() {

    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();

    //check if user is login
    Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    if (!(auth instanceof AnonymousAuthenticationToken)) {
        UserDetails userDetail = (UserDetails) auth.getPrincipal();
        model.addObject("username", userDetail.getUsername());
    }

    model.setViewName("403");
    return model;
}
```

My CustomUserDetailService.java

```
@Component("customUserDetailsService")
public class CustomUserDetailService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;


    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String login) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        //our domain entity User
        User userToAuthorise = userService.getByLogin(login);
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = buildUserAuthority(userToAuthorise.getUserRoles());

        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(userToAuthorise.getLogin(),
                userToAuthorise.getPassword(), authorities);
    }

    private List<GrantedAuthority> buildUserAuthority(List<UserRole> userRoles) {

        List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> listAuth = new ArrayList<>();
        // Build user's authorities
        for (UserRole userRole : userRoles) {
            listAuth.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(userRole.getRole()));
        }
        return new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>(listAuth);
    }
```

My CustomSuccessHandler.java

```
public class CustomSuccessHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler {

private RedirectStrategy redirectStrategy = new DefaultRedirectStrategy();

@Override
public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,
        HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse,
        Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
    String targetUrl = getSuccessUrl(authentication);
    redirectStrategy.sendRedirect(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse, targetUrl);
    clearAuthenticationAttributes(httpServletRequest);
}

private String getSuccessUrl(final Authentication authentication) {
    boolean isUser = false;
    boolean isAdmin = false;
    final Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities = authentication.getAuthorities();
    for (final GrantedAuthority grantedAuthority : authorities) {
        if (grantedAuthority.getAuthority().equals("ROLE_USER")) {
            isUser = true;
            break;
        } else if (grantedAuthority.getAuthority().equals("ROLE_ADMIN")) {
            isAdmin = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (isUser) {
        return "/user";
    } else if (isAdmin) {
        return "/admin";
    } else {
        throw new IllegalStateException();
    }
}

protected final void clearAuthenticationAttributes(final HttpServletRequest request) {
    final HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);

    if (session == null) {
        return;
    }

    session.removeAttribute(WebAttributes.AUTHENTICATION_EXCEPTION);
}
```

Thank for Your answers!

Comment: Maybe the browser is remembering the password?

Comment: Nope, i have checked it (

Comment: Your configuration is wrong. When securing URLs the ordering of the url patterns matters. You are providing access to all URLs first and then try to limit it, that will not work. The determine if a url can be accessed the order they are declared in is also the order on how they are consulted, so basically you don't have any security at all in your application.